# How do I set 'selective-input' to a form field in Angular?

Tags: javascript, angular, forms, typescript, autocorrect

I have a form input field in angular that is to be filled with a number.

How can I set it up in a way that when you try to add any other character that is not a number, nothing happens. How can my form work as if only integer keys on the keyboard are working? For example if my form has 100 and I try to input a character like the plus sign nothing happens?

[here is the code](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-bwmg9h?file=app%2Fform-field-prefix-suffix-example.ts) for my form.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want your input to be only number you can specify that with type property, for example:

```
<input type="number" />
```

and it will accept only integers.

Comment: Thank you.. this works. But how do I get rid of the up and down arrows that are used to add and subtract the value of the number since I have buttons for that?

Comment: Just found an [answer](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/turn-off-number-input-spinners/) to my question in the comments. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You can also subscribe to the keydown event for that input:

```
// in your template
<input (keydown)='onKeyDown($event)' ...>

// in your component
onKeyDown(event: KeyboardEvent) {
  if (!event.key.match(/[0-9]{1}|Delete|ArrowUp|ArrowDown|ArrowLeft|ArrowRight|Backspace/)) {
    event.preventDefault();
  }
}
```

Note that you will have to allow for the navigation keys and delete keys, etc as well.